# Business connectivity services return no data from web service

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, bcs

I am having trouble with `Read List` operation. The operation calls a method from my service which accepts one parameter, **Title**.

If default value is set as `null` or `none` in operation settings, then no data is returned. But, if I call the same service from any other application (Postman, Wizdler, etc.) and pass an empty string, then all the data is returned.